# Setting the id of a link based on it's href

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, href, attr

```
$('.portfolioThumbs ul li a').mouseover(
    function(){
        var buttLink = $(this).attr('href') 
        var buttLinkArray = buttLink.split( '/' ); // Split the URL after each / and Create an array of each
        var pFN = buttLinkArray[2]; // We want the Portfolio Folder Name
        var url = window.location.pathname;

        $('.galleryNav ul li a').removeClass('hovered');
        $('.galleryNav ul li a' + '#' + pFN).addClass('hovered');
        window.location.pathname = url + '#' + pFN;
    }       
);
```

This code allows me to set an ID on each button based on its href when the user "mouseover's" it. Does anyone know how this can be done automatically when the page loads, so that each button in the list gets and ID based on it's href, without any user interaction.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: instead of mouseover, do onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all links on page load. If you are using jQuery 1.7+ then use `prop` to set the href attribute. Otherwise use `attr`.

```
$('.portfolioThumbs ul li a').each(
    function(){
        var buttLink = $(this).attr('href')  //do you really want attr or do you want prop?
        var buttLinkArray = buttLink.split( '/' ); // Split the URL after each / and Create an array of each
        var pFN = buttLinkArray[2]; // We want the Portfolio Folder Name
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        $(this).prop('href', url);
    }       
);
```

Comment: Super, thanks for this. So obvious when you know how! This is only half of the problem though. Any ideas how you assign the relevant id to each link? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know what `relevant id` is. If you want to set the id of an element you use `$(this).prop('id', 'myNewId');

Comment: Thanks @mrtsherman! I'm just over thinking things. I need to let jQuery do its magic. This is spot on! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can run code after the document loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```